# How to convert .csv file to .md using python

Tags: python, csv, markdown

Input csv file content:

```
Loop Count,1000,,,,,
Data1,Artefact,,,,,
,TWHashTable,,,,,
 , ,Insert,TBB:892,TW:6242,,
 , ,Find,TBB:203,TW:721,,
 , ,DeleteAll,TBB:33,TW:1372369,,
Data2,Artefact,,,,,
,TWUtils,,,,
 , ,Insert,TBB:892,TW:6242,,
 , ,Find,TBB:203,TW:721,,
 , ,DeleteAll,TBB:33,TW:1372369,,
```

## Expected output:

| Loop Count | 1000 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 | FIELD6 | FIELD7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Artefact |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | TWHashTable |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Insert | TBB:892 | TW:6242 |  |  |
|  |  | Find | TBB:203 | TW:721 |  |  |
|  |  | DeleteAll | TBB:33 | TW:1372369 |  |  |
| Data2 | Artefact |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | TWUtils |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Insert | TBB:892 | TW:6242 |  |  |
|  |  | Find | TBB:203 | TW:721 |  |  |
|  |  | DeleteAll | TBB:33 | TW:1372369 |  |  |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file.csv")
with open("my_markdown.md", 'w') as md:
  df.to_markdown(buf=md, tablefmt="grid")
```

Check more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html)

Comment: Thank you, it worked with
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, engine='python')

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, engine='python')
with open("my_markdown.md", 'w') as md:
    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    df.to_markdown(buf=md, index=False)
```